# JSCS hangs when excludeFiles property added to .jscsrc

Tags: javascript, jscs

I installed istanbul to catch coverage on my tests, which started to cause jscs to throw a lot of errors on the coverage directory.

I tried putting `"excludeFiles": ["coverage/**", "test/fixtures/**"]` into my .jscsrc file but now that is causing jscs to hang indefinitely when I run it. control c does not work to exit.

I tried a couple different patterns including just the directory and with a preceding ./ for the path name. Same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out it works when I put it at the top of the rc file.